# How can i repeat a switch statement in C?

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement, repeat

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void){
 int a;
 int attempt;
 int answer;
 int f;
 int difficulty;
 int end;

 printf("GUESS THE NUMBER\n");
 printf("guess the number chosen on a scale of 1 to 100\n");
 printf("\n");

do{
 srand(time(NULL));
 a=rand()%100+1;
 attempt=1;

 printf("Choose Difficulty\n");
 printf("1.Easy   2.Normal   3.Hard\n");
 scanf("%d", &difficulty);

 switch(difficulty){
   case 1:{
        f=15;
        break;
   }
   case 2:{
        f=10;
        break;
   }
   case 3:{
        f=5;
        break;
   }
   default: printf("Invalid value\n");
 }

 printf("\n");
 printf("You have %d attempts to guess the chosen number\n",f)
 printf("At each attempt you will be given a clue\n")

while(attempt<=f){
 int remaining=f-attempt;
 printf("\nattempt number %d:\n",attempt);
 scanf("%d",&answer);

 if(answer>a){
    if((difficulty=1)){
       if(answer-a<=5){
           printf("The value entered is slightly bigger\n");
           attempt++;
       }
       else if(answer-a>5&&answer-a<=10{
           printf("The value entered is bigger\n");
           attempt++;
       }
       else if(answer-a>10){
           printf("The value entered is much bigger\n");
           attempt++;
       }
    }
 }
 else if((answer<a){
    if((difficulty=1)){
       if(a-answer<=5){
           printf("The value entered is slightly smaller\n");
           attempt++;
       }
       else if(a-answer>5&&answer-a<=10{
           printf("The value entered is smaller\n");
           attempt++;
       }
       else if(a-answer>10){
           printf("The value entered is much smaller\n");
           attempt++;
       }
    }
 }
 else if((answer=a)){
    printf("GUESSED\n");
    printf("attempts made: %d\n",attempt);
    printf("remaining attempts: %d\n,remaining);
    printf("Do you want to play again? 1=Yes  0=No\n");
    scanf("%d",&end);
    break;
 }

 }
 printf("\nGame Over\n");
 printf("the number chosen was %d\n",a);
 printf("Do you want to try again? 1=Yes  0=No\n");
 scanf("%d",&end);
}
while((end==1));
return 0;
}
```

This is currently my program, I want to create a loop in the switch so it repeats every time an incorrect value is entered. How can I do?
By incorrect value I mean anything entered that is not 1,2 or 3.
Also if there are other errors in the program please let me note. I apologize if I used unclear English.

Comment: Add a flag `valid`, which you will set in your `switch` statement. Then `while(!valid)....`

Comment: Side comment - consider moving some of the logic into functions. It will make the code easier to read/maintain, and will get you a better grade!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to actually add a variable/flag indicating if you actually received a correct statement. If you receive `1 2 or 3` simply turn that flag to `1`, and in the while statement put simply: `while(!flag)`.
So the code would be:

```
int flag=1;
while(flag){
switch(difficulty){
   case 1:{
        f=15;
        flag=0;
        break;
   }
   case 2:{
        f=10;
        flag=0;
        break;
   }
   case 3:{
        f=5;
        flag=0;
        break;
   }
   default: printf("Invalid value\n");
 }
}
```

Remember to always set the flag to 1.
PS: A flag can be set with an int variable that changes between 0 and 1, depending on what you want to represent.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to write a method to validate the input:

```
int validateInput( int difficulty ) {
    switch(difficulty){
    case 1:{
        return 15;
    case 2:
        return 10;
    '''
    default: 
        // write error message here
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then in main:

```
   int f = -1;
   ...
   while ( f < 0 ) {
      // read "difficulty" here
      ...
      f = validateInput( difficulty ) ;
  }
```

Also include a special value of difficulty to allow the user to give up (avoiding an infinite loop).